# Creating custom textboxes for SSRS - does it make sense?

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services

I just had the thought that some things would be easier for me in SSRS 2008 R2 if I could create custom controls, such as a textbox that had my standard font, plus the Expression prefilled as `Parameters!DateBegin.Value + "-" + Parameters!DateEnd.Value` (or thereabouts). Does this make any sense, or is this not how custom controls are meant to be used?

Thanks.